# How to dispatch in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, use-reducer

I tried to set a state using `useState` inside `useEffect` with no problem, code as follows:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Banner = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const api = 'some api url';
      let response = await fetch(api);
      response = await response.json();
      setTitle(response.title);
    }
    fetchData();
  })
}

export default Banner;
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing but with useReducer, I tried to modify the above code to the following but no luck:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const bannerReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'setTitle':
      return {
        ...state,
        title: state.title
      }
  }
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(bannerReducer, {title: []});

const Banner = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const api = 'some api url';
      let response = await fetch(api);
      response = await response.json();
      dispatch({type: 'setTitle', response.title});
    }
    fetchData();
  })
}

export default Banner;
```

How can I use useReducer in this case?

Comment: Also, Dispatch should be dispatch({type: 'setTitle', title: response.title});
and inside reducer return should be title: action.title instead of title: state.title

Comment: As an aside, you should make sure you are always returning the current state when not handling an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the reducer with the same state property as it was before in this case you're basically doing:

```
title: state.title
```

And since your default state is a title with an empty array value you're not changing anything.

You need to use the action argument in your reducer to accomplish what you want:

```
const bannerReducer = (state, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'setTitle':
   return {
    ...state,
    title: action.title
   }
  }
}
```

And your dispatch should be something like this:

```
dispatch({type: 'setTitle', title: response.title});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useReducer` call is not inside the function, therefore doesn't get attached to it.
Call it like this:

```js
const Banner = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(bannerReducer, {title: []});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const api = 'some api url';
      let response = await fetch(api);
      response = await response.json();
      dispatch({type: 'setTitle', response.title});
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
}
```

Also keep in mind that your `useEffect` runs every time the `Banner` function gets called. Consider adding a dependencies array as stated here in the hooks tutorial: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: And add a `[ ]` to the second parameter of the `useEffect()` because of this makes infinity loop.